# Is there a standard way to document groovy map properties?

Tags: groovy, javadoc, groovydoc

Is there a standard way to document map properties in Groovy?

For the following function the config contains multiple optional properties like:

- `ignore`
- `dir`
- `tags`

```
def publish(Map config) {
  config.ignore ?= true
  // ...
}
```

I looked at [What is the standard way to use JavaDoc to document a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944539/what-is-the-standard-way-to-use-javadoc-to-document-a-map) ; however, this doesn't work with dynamic Maps. Ideally I'm looking for something like JSDoc's `@typedef` or [`@property`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than adding the options to some JavaDoc for your method, there's no real way to document these...

If this is a public API which requires documentation, you could move to passing actual parameters or you could create a class which is used for passing these options, ie:

```
import groovy.transform.ToString
import groovy.transform.Immutable

@ToString
@Immutable
class Options {
    boolean debug = false
    File dir = new File('.')
    List<String> tags = []
}

println new Options()
println new Options(debug: true, dir: new File("/tmp"))
println new Options(tags: ['a', 'b'])
```

Which prints

```
Options(false, ., [])
Options(true, /tmp, [])
Options(false, ., [a, b])
```